# Restarting OpenVPN server causes connected clients to stall

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have a small OpenVPN based network tying together a bunch of VPS's and I noticed that when I add a new client and restart the OpenVPN server to expose the IP address of the new client, the already connected clients will stall for 1 to 2 mins after which they will be able to see the OpenVPN server again.

The way I tested this is by having my already connected VPN clients to ping the VPN server (`ping 10.8.0.1`). When I add a new client I create a file containing the IP address of the new client in the `ccd/newclient` file. E.g:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.5 10.8.0.6
```

After doing this I restart my OpenVPN server with `service openvpn restart`. At this point the new client is pretty much able to see the server immediately, but the already connected clients will stall for 1 to 2 minutes after which they will start pinging again.

I tried using `service openvpn reload` on the VPN server instead but the behaviour seems to be the same.

What is the best way to add a new client to an existing OpenVPN network without impacting the already existing clients in the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, it is not necessary to restart OpenVPN for a new client file in the client config dir.  Indeed, from the man page:

> One  of  the  useful properties of this option is that it allows 
>   client configuration files to be conveniently  created,  edited,  or 
>   removed while the server is live, without needing to restart  the
>   server